# Allocating memory on heap in python

Tags: python

Does python support dynamic memory allocation? (similar to `malloc()`,`calloc()` in `c`)
If yes, how to allocate a memory for an object on `heap`?

Comment: What do you need dynamic allocations for?

Comment: Here's something which you can refer to: http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/memory.html

Comment: @thefourtheye: Well, i worked on a project in c++ where I used dynamic memory allocation. I need to know if I can do the same using python.

Comment: Memory for objects is allocated and reclaimed automatically in Python. It's not something you normally have to be concerned with managing except to make sure you don't try to use too much of it at once.

Comment: If your project requires allocating memory in a specific way, python is not the language you should be using.

Comment: One of the benefits of a high-level language is that it abstracts away these kinds of considerations. You can't control them, and shouldn't want to. The inplementation does things one way today, and perhaps another tomorrow. If you absolutely need to control this, you chose the wrong tool (or need to understand the selected implementation's internals really well).

Answer (score 6):

Generally, you won't be worrying about memory allocation in Python. You can treat all objects as lying on the heap; they probably *will* all lie on the heap, though there might be some optimizations somewhere that put a few on the stack.

```
c = []
```

This will allocate a list on the heap. When the list is no longer reachable from any chain of references, it will be available for garbage collection, and it will probably be freed. More generally, anything that creates an object can be safely treated as allocating it on the heap.

Comment: Can you please give some citations? So that we can go ahead and read more about this.